# mysql pivot not counting Date columns

Tags: mysql, pivot

I hope someone can help me see through this query which has been working on another database but now fails.

The below is based on a pivot table with source on left and months across left to right, all works fine except one column which just refuses to be counted!

`Count(l.CompDate) As Submitted` outputs the same number as `Count(l.id) As Leads`, the `l.ComDate` field is a date based column, if there column has a date in it should be counted but its not, it just counts all records.

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong? I have been on this for days.

```
Select *,   If(q.Source Is Null, 1, 0) As remove From  
(Select l.Source,      
Sum(Month(l.CompDate) = 1) As Jan, 
Sum(Month(l.CompDate) = 2) As Feb,
Sum(Month(l.CompDate) = 3) As Mar,       
Sum(Month(l.CompDate) = 4) As Apr,      
Sum(Month(l.CompDate) = 5) As May,       
Sum(Month(l.CompDate) = 6) As Jun,       
Sum(Month(l.CompDate) = 7) As Jul,       
Sum(Month(l.CompDate) = 8) As Aug,       
Sum(Month(l.CompDate) = 9) As Sep,       
Sum(Month(l.CompDate) = 10) As Oct,       
Sum(Month(l.CompDate) = 11) As Nov,       
Sum(Month(l.CompDate) = 12) As Decb,
Count(l.id) As Leads,
Count(l.CompDate) As Submitted,
ROUND(Count(l.id)*100 / (Count(l.CompDate)), 2) As Conversion
From       tbl_lead l     
Where       Year(l.LeadDate) = 2015     
Group By  l.Source With Rollup) q
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
Count(l.CompDate) As Submitted,
```

Does exactly what you are expressing.  It is counting the `non-NULL` values of `l.CompDate`.

It is unclear what you want.  If you want the number of distinct *date* values, then one of the following would work:

```
Count(distinct l.CompDate) As Submitted,

Count(distinct date(l.CompDate)) As Submitted,
```

Comment: Hi there and thank you. This table has 6 records so the 'Count(l.id) As Leads' outputs correctly 6. There are only 3 records with a value in 'Count(l.CompDate) As Submitted', these on the sample table have same date values but its counting it as 6 the total number of records in the table and not columns with date value?

Ideally this should show 6 Leads | 3 Submitted

Comment: @GaryBrett . . . Hence the `count(distinct)`.  Did you even try the answer?